# Restructuring CSV into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've got a CSV with a rather messy format:

```
t, 01_x, 01_y, 02_x, 02_y
0,     0,    1,    ,
1,     1,    1,   0,    0
```

Thereby "01_" and "02_" are numbers of entities (1, 2), which can vary from file to file and there might be additional columns too (but at least the same for all entities).
Note also that entity 2 enters the scene at t=1 (no entries at t=0).

I already import the CSV into a pandas dataframe, but don't see the way to transform the stuff into the following form:

```
t, entity, x, y
0,      1, 0, 1
1,      1, 1, 1
1       2, 0, 0
```

Is there a simple (pythonic) way to transform that?

Thanks!
René

Comment: Please do not edit questions which already have an answer as they were asked in a way that it invalidates said answer. Please consider undoing your edit. If a given answer makes you realise that you actually wanted to ask a different question, then please create that new different question by using the "Ask Question" button again.

Comment: @Yunnosch I disagree. There's no harm, and typically only benefit, in editing questions until an answer **is accepted**. In this case the sample data and expected output remained unchanged and only clarifying details were added. Suggesting that people shouldn't edit because someone jumped to add an answer (in this case without fully understanding the question), is the fault of the answerer, not the asker.

Comment: @ALollz Opinions divide. Mine is that an answer which gets downvotes because it does not answer the question after the edit is a reason for the author to be frustrated, i.e. it is unfair towards those who spend effort on the attempt to help. By the way, when do you expect an answer to be accepted, which gets then invalidated by an edit to the question? Usually such an answer makes the OP aware of what they later change, by not answering the question they actually mean... I hope you do not suspect akers here to think "Good, that solved problem A. Now lets ask here about problem B.". The horror!

Comment: Sorry @HaydenEastwood, I tried to defend you by enlightening OP...

Comment: Admittedly, rolling back now would probably invalidate the now only existing answer... Sigh.

Comment: It was not a different question and as such I dared to edit the question. I just made clear, that I already use pandas. Well, the question was already tagged with "pandas" and used DataFrame within the question. Yet, the very first answer I got was "import into pandas" which was immediatly downvoted by someone else. It's also frustrating for the author to get sloppy quick shots. But I also see, that there I no good way in dealing with such situations. So I try to stick to answers instead of edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), but we need to first swap the order of your column names around the `'_'`

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1]) for x in df.columns]
#Index(['t', 'x_01', 'y_01', 'x_02', 'y_02'], dtype='object')

(pd.wide_to_long(df, i='t', j='entity', stubnames=['x', 'y'], sep='_')
   .dropna()
   .reset_index())
```

---

```
   t  entity    x    y
0  0       1  0.0  1.0
1  1       1  1.0  1.0
2  1       2  0.0  0.0
```